# Why I am getting undefined index but I already dump my array and its has values on it?

Tags: php, arrays

I dont know whats wrong but why I have undefined index since I already dump my array and it has values what could be wrong or I am missing?

//Here's the screenshot:
[image]

//Here's my php code:

```
$result1 = array(); //for player 1
$result2 = array(); //for player 2

$data_blue = $db->dataWarrior($battle,$blue_name,$blue_type);

foreach($data_blue as $blue){
    $result1[] = $blue;
}

$data_red = $db->dataWarrior($battle,$red_name,$red_type);

foreach($data_red as $red){
    $result2[] = $red;
}

var_dump($result1);

//variables to identify turns 1=turn
$warrior_1 = 0;
$warrior_2 = 0;

//compare speed
if($result1['speed']>$result2['speed']){ //this is the undefined index
    $warrior_1 = 1;
    $warrior_2 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$result1[] = $blue;
```

nests one array within another.

```
if($result1[0]['speed']>$result2[0]['speed']){
```

Or just assign instead of appending in the earlier lines.

```
$result1 = $blue;
```

Comment: if I want to access other values still the same use [0]?

Comment: $result1 = $blue; on my foreach ?

Comment: Yeah, the `$result1[] = blue;` line means you're adding a new blue_warrior array to the end of the `$result1` array.

Comment: Basically, if you have 5 blue warriors in $data_blue, your $result1 will contain 5 blue warrior arrays. `$result1[0], $result1[1], $result1[2], $result1[3], $result1[4]`. If you only have one blue warrior, you might as well do `$result1 = $blue;`

Answer (score 3):

Your array starts with an index of 0.

Try

```
if($result1[0]['speed']>$result2[0]['speed']){
```

Comment: The issue is not that the array starts with an index of 0, it's that the arrays are nested.